# Page not found http://127.0.0.1:8000/manageAccount/a/delete

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I don't know why I get this page because I think all works right. I couldn't identify why the browser gives this error but below url is not worked because user object not get because its redirect on login page but i am going on  this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_homeview/a/delete  its work successfully but user_homeview that template is after login show means homepage i dont know what can i do please tell me:

> Page not found http://127.0.0.1:8000/manageAccount/a/delete

Here is my code:

template.html:

```
<a href="{{ request.user }}/delete" class="ml-4">Delete Account</a><Br>
```

urls.py:

```
path('<str:username>/delete', delete_user, name='delete-user')
```

views.py:

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}

    u = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    u.delete()
    messages.success(request,'your account delete')
    return render(request, 'home/login.html', context=context)
```

Comment: I think instead of rendering u should redirect to home page after deleting

Comment: As @Sheraram_Prajapat mentioned you need to redirect your user to another view, because you are rendering a page with the delete url of the user. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 0):

Check on your developer tools what is being rendered on your  href attribute. I think the url is not being rendered correctly by your current template tag. It should be like this, according to Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<a href="{% url 'delete-user' request.user %}" class="ml-4">Delete Account</a><Br>
```

Note that you don't have access to `request` by default in your templates. If you are deleting a user by its username, the previous code would be:

```
<a href="{% url 'delete-user' user.username %}" class="ml-4">Delete Account</a><Br>
```

as `user` is accessible by default in your templates.

Be aware that this is not the secure way of deleting users, as anyone with other user's information can access this link to delete accounts. You should use POST requests and check if the user requesting the delete link is the owner of the account.